# my dropdown menu is pushing objects in css

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I know, I know... there is a lot questions about this subject here at stackoverflow, but for some mysterious,god only knows, reasons it did not helped me.

```css
 {
   list-style: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
 body {
   background-image: url(../images/pozadina.jpg);
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
 #CenterRectangle {
   width: 200px;
   height: 320px;
   background: white;
   border-radius: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -155px;
   margin-left: -100px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 4px 5px white;
   z-index: -1;
   opacity: 0.7;
 }
 nav {
   width: 100px;
   height: 60px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 210px 630px;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   border-radius: 20px;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
 }
 nav a {
   display: block;
   color: black;
   width: 100px;
   line-height: 50px;
   background-color: #81CFE0;
   margin-top: 5px;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 20px;
   transition: opacity 1s;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
 }
 nav a:first-child {
   opacity: 1
 }
 nav:hover {
   height: auto;
 }
 nav:hover a {
   opacity: 1
 }
 nav a:hover {
   background-color: #E4F1FE;
 }
 .Socialbtns {
   z-index: -1;
   margin: -10px 600px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Your Website!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="TopRectangle"></div>
  <div id="BottomRectangle"></div>
  <div id="CenterRectangle"></div>

  <div class="container">

    <nav>
      <a href="">HOME</a>
      <a href="">About Us</a>
      <a href="">Products</a>
      <a href="">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="Socialbtns">
      <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

First if i put 'position:absolute' in my 'nav a' then dropdown menu is simple broken,it won't open.

Second if i put 'position:absolute' in 'nav' then my menu just go on right and still continue to push my content down;

I put black cloud just for example so that you can see what's happening.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you replicate this on plunkr/fiddle

Comment: You currently don't have a dropdown menu at all. You have a bunch of links stacked on top of one another. That's it. As far as your cloud moving, that's because you're changing the `height` of your `<nav>` when you hover it from `height: 60px;` to `height: auto;`. @RandomChannel they have included a snippet.

Comment: I have to agree with you hungerstar. You just hover over the home button and it changes to a button that says Contacts.

Comment: Oh my mistake i put the wrong code. I guess frustation killed me. Here is fiddle link: [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/gojic/g02jz2xj/)

Comment: @gojic You need to update your post as well. Have you actually looked into how to build a dropdown? If you had, your solution would look a lot different. Again, content is getting pushed around because you're changing the height of the `<nav>`.